# Wix: Events Tracking in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I went through the tutorial to set this up (at https://support.wix.com/en/article/wix-code-tutorial-sending-tracking-and-analytics-events) but I can't see the events in Google Analytics. My configuration is the following:

I have a button on one of my pages with the id of `downloadButtonNewbornBrochure` which as its name says is linked to a file download. I placed the following code on the page:

```
// For full API documentation, including code examples, visit http://wix.to/94BuAAs
import wixWindow from 'wix-window';

export function downloadButtonNewbornBrochure_click(event) {
  wixWindow.trackEvent("CustomEvent", {
 "event": "Download",
 "eventCategory": "Newborn",
 "eventAction": "Brochure Download"
  } );
}

$w.onReady(function () {
 //TODO: write your page related code here...
});
```

In Google Analytics I have a Goal specified and enabled:

> Custom goal
>
> Goal name: Download
>
> Type: Event
>
> Category Equal To Newborn
>
> Action Equal To Brochure Download
>
> Label empty
>
> Value empty
>
> Use the Event value as the Goal Value for the conversion: yes

When I verify or test this button, no events are captured. Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: have you tried in another browser or in incognito mode? Maybe wix doesn't trigger events if you're logged in as admin?

Comment: The trackEvent() function only runs on published versions of your site. It does not work when previewing your site.

Comment: Hi, I have published the site.